# OpenGL offscreen rendering and reading the pixel values with a HIDDEN window using glfw

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I need to render a 3d model into many views and the image size is much larger than screen resolution, so I can not open a so large window and I do not need to open a window to see the rendering result, too. I only want to render the 3d model into many images with different viewpoints.

I find this tutorial, http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/, and I try to use glGetTexImage and glReadPixels to read pixel values from fbo.

The problem is if the window is not hidden, it is OK. If I set the window hidden using

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);
```

I can only read the background color from fbo using glGetTexImage or glReadPixels. And the model drawed using glDrawElements disappears.

Could anyone help me or show me an example? Thanks!

This my code of reading fbo: (It work well if the window is not hidden, the remaining part of my code is same as http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/)

Here is my code is:

```
if (!glfwInit())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_TRUE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
int windowWidth = 4000;
int windowHeight = 3000;

window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Tutorial 14 - Render To Texture", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
// Hide the mouse and enable unlimited mouvement
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

// Set the mouse at the center of the screen
glfwPollEvents();
glfwSetCursorPos(window, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// Enable depth test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
// Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

// Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders("StandardShadingRTT.vertexshader", "StandardShadingRTT.fragmentshader");

// Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");
GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");

// Load the texture
GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvmap.DDS");

// Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
GLuint TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");

// Read our .obj file
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
bool res = loadOBJ("suzanne.obj", vertices, uvs, normals);

std::vector<unsigned short> indices;
std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> indexed_uvs;
std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_normals;
indexVBO(vertices, uvs, normals, indices, indexed_vertices, indexed_uvs, indexed_normals);

// Load it into a VBO
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &indexed_uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLuint normalbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Generate a buffer for the indices as well
GLuint elementbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Get a handle for our "LightPosition" uniform
glUseProgram(programID);
GLuint LightID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPosition_worldspace");


// ---------------------------------------------
// Render to Texture - specific code begins here
// ---------------------------------------------

// The framebuffer, which regroups 0, 1, or more textures, and 0 or 1 depth buffer.
GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

// The texture we're going to render to
GLuint renderedTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

// "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

// Give an empty image to OpenGL ( the last "0" means "empty" )
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

// Poor filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// Set "renderedTexture" as our colour attachement #0
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);
// Set the list of draw buffers.
GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers
// Always check that our framebuffer is ok
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    return false;

// Render to our framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); // Render on the whole framebuffer, complete from the lower left corner to the upper right
// Clear the screen
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Use our shader
glUseProgram(programID);
// Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
computeMatricesFromInputs();
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

// Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
// in the "MVP" uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);

glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(4, 4, 4);
glUniform3f(LightID, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

// Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
// Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

// 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,                  // attribute
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    0,                  // stride
    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

// 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    1,                                // attribute
    2,                                // size
    GL_FLOAT,                         // type
    GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
    0,                                // stride
    (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

// 3rd attribute buffer : normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    2,                                // attribute
    3,                                // size
    GL_FLOAT,                         // type
    GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
    0,                                // stride
    (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

// Index buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

// Draw the triangles !
glDrawElements(
    GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
    indices.size(),    // count
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, // type
    (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
    );

unsigned char *image = new unsigned char[windowWidth * windowHeight * 3];
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

cv::Mat img;
img = cv::Mat::zeros(windowHeight, windowWidth, CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < windowHeight; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < windowWidth; j ++) {
        int index = (i * windowWidth + j) * 3;
        cv::Vec3b px;
        px.val[0] = image[index + 0];
        px.val[1] = image[index + 1];
        px.val[2] = image[index + 2];
        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = px;
    }
}

cv::imwrite("test.png", img);
```

It works very well when the window is visible

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);
```

but if I set it to be GL_TRUE, I can not get the results any more!

Could any one help me? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: Rendering to a hidden part of the window gives unspecified results. Render to some off-screen framebuffer instead.

Comment: I already render to framebuffer object, but I do not know if my code is right. Could you give me any examples?

Comment: Oops, I didn't realise you were already using a framebuffer.

Comment: @XiaoyunYuan: "*I already render to framebuffer object*" Do you? Where? I see no code where you build your FBO. I see no code where you render to it. I only see one line about binding one, and that one's pointless since you're not doing anything with it. So where is your code? You should be able to post a [mcve] where you just clear the screen to a color.

Comment: To anyone wanting to do offscreen rendering with GLFW, as of august 2017, real offscreen rendering [is not currently possible](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/648): on Linux you need a X server for instance (even if the window is hidden). See also [this link](http://discourse.glfw.org/t/off-screen-rendering-and-x-windows/784).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this example? It uses Frame Buffer

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_texture_.282D.29

Code below (in case the link gets broken on the future):

```
   //RGBA8 2D texture, 24 bit depth texture, 256x256
   glGenTextures(1, &color_tex);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_tex);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   //NULL means reserve texture memory, but texels are undefined
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
   //-------------------------
   glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fb);
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb);
   //Attach 2D texture to this FBO
   glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_tex, 0);
   //-------------------------
   glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &depth_rb);
   glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth_rb);
   glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 256, 256);
   //-------------------------
   //Attach depth buffer to FBO
   glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth_rb);
   //-------------------------
   //Does the GPU support current FBO configuration?
   GLenum status;
   status = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);
   switch(status)
   {
      case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT:
      cout<<"good";
       default:
      HANDLE_THE_ERROR;
   }
   //-------------------------
   //and now you can render to GL_TEXTURE_2D
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb);
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClearDepth(1.0f);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   //-------------------------
   glViewport(0, 0, 256, 256);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, 256.0, 0.0, 256.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   //-------------------------
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   //-------------------------
   //**************************
   //RenderATriangle, {0.0, 0.0}, {256.0, 0.0}, {256.0, 256.0}
   //Read http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples
   RenderATriangle();
   //-------------------------
   GLubyte pixels[4*4*4];
   glReadPixels(0, 0, 4, 4, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
   //pixels 0, 1, 2 should be white
   //pixel 4 should be black
   //----------------
   //Bind 0, which means render to back buffer
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

Code cleanup:

```
   //Delete resources
   glDeleteTextures(1, &color_tex);
   glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT(1, &depth_rb);
   //Bind 0, which means render to back buffer, as a result, fb is unbound
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
   glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, &fb);
```

Comment: I have put all my code in question and I still can not to render the image if setting glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);